# How to wrap legend text in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the head of my data:

```
structure(list(aasta = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020), tunnus1 = c("Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", "Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", "Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", "Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", "Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate arv", "Vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate arv", "Vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate arv", "Vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate arv", "Vanaduspensionile minejate arv", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate arv"), vaartus1 = c(1022, 1173, 1129, 
1083, 1294, 1026, 862, 751, 764, 6529, 7683, 6797, 6892, 8106, 
6922, 6502, 6098, 5817), tunnus2 = c("Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Ennetähtaegselt vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal  VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest", 
"Vanaduspensionile minejate osakaal kõigist eelmisel aastal VTI-dest"
), vaartus2 = c(0.01, 0.011, 0.01, 0.01, 0.012, 0.009, 0.008, 
0.007, 0.007, 0.066, 0.073, 0.063, 0.064, 0.074, 0.062, 0.059, 
0.057, 0.054)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My colors:

```
cen_col_palette <- function(){
  c("#1C5679",
    "#808C5C",
    "#BF2124",
    "#D88F2E",
    "#5F4B3B",
    "#BBB592",
    "#87240E",
    "#7A989A",
    "#204035",
    "#F4CE4B",
    "#805730",
    "#D4613E",
    "#212F3D",
    "#145A32",
    "#808080",
    "#E74C3C")
}
cen_cols <- cen_col_palette()
```

This is my plot:

```
ggplot(ennet1, aes(y = vaartus2, x = aasta, group=tunnus2, label=scales::percent(vaartus2,decimal.mark=',',accuracy = 0.1)))+
  geom_line(aes(color=tunnus2, linetype=tunnus2))+
  geom_point(aes(color=tunnus2))+
  geom_label(vjust = -0.6, label.size = 0, label.padding = unit(0.3, "lines"), size = 3.5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2012,2020,by=2))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(decimal.mark = ',',accuracy=1), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.5)))+
  cen_theme()+
  theme(
    strip.background =element_blank(),
    strip.text =element_text(size=11),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 11))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = cen_cols)+
  scale_color_manual(values = cen_cols)+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11, hjust=0.5))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.key.height=unit(2, "cm"))+
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.box="vertical", legend.margin=margin())
```

This is what the graph looks like right now:

[image]

As you can see the legend titles are too long and I would like to wrap them. I tried library(stringr) and adding str_wrap, but really I don't know where to put it and it did not work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your text using `guide_legend` with two rows and change `size` of text in `legend.text`. You can use this code:

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(ennet1, aes(y = vaartus2, x = aasta, group=tunnus2, label=scales::percent(vaartus2,decimal.mark=',',accuracy = 0.1)))+
  geom_line(aes(color=tunnus2, linetype=tunnus2))+
  geom_point(aes(color=tunnus2))+
  geom_label(vjust = -0.6, label.size = 0, label.padding = unit(0.3, "lines"), size = 3.5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2012,2020,by=2))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(decimal.mark = ',',accuracy=1), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.5)))+
  #cen_theme()+
  theme(
    strip.background =element_blank(),
    strip.text =element_text(size=11),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 11))+
  #scale_fill_manual(values = cen_cols)+
  #scale_color_manual(values = cen_cols)+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11, hjust=0.5))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.key.height=unit(2, "cm"))+
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.box="vertical", legend.margin=margin()) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8)) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a function to the `labels` argument of the scale. To wrap your labels using `strings::str_wrap` you could use e.g. `labels = ~ stringr::str_wrap(.x, width = 20)`.

Note: As you use three aesthetics (or scales) you have to do that for each of your scales, i.e. `color`, `fill` and `linetype`. Otherwise the legends will not get merged.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ennet1, aes(y = vaartus2, x = aasta, group = tunnus2, label = scales::percent(vaartus2, decimal.mark = ",", accuracy = 0.1))) +
  geom_line(aes(color = tunnus2, linetype = tunnus2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = tunnus2)) +
  geom_label(vjust = -0.6, label.size = 0, label.padding = unit(0.3, "lines"), size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2012, 2020, by = 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(decimal.mark = ",", accuracy = 1), expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.5))) +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 11),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 11),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 11)
  ) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(labels = ~ stringr::str_wrap(.x, width = 20)) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = ~ stringr::str_wrap(.x, width = 20), values = cen_cols) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = ~ stringr::str_wrap(.x, width = 20), values = cen_cols) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11, hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.box = "vertical", legend.margin = margin())
```

[image]

Comment: This looks exactly like I want it, but somehow it didn't work for me. I copied your code, but it completely deleted my legend text. Can't figure out why. Instead my legend text now says ::(stringr, str_wrap)(.x,20). I also tried it with scale_color_manual etc. I also added my colors to my original post.

Comment: Hm. Not sure what's the issue. I just edited my code to use `scale_xxx_manual` and your colors.