# Ordering ggplot2 legend to agree with factor order of bars in geom_col when plotting data from tabyl

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, janitor

I've looked through dozens of posts with similar issues but none have provided a solution to my problem so I'm posting here. I have categorical data for which I'm producing descriptive statistics (counts, percentages, and confidence bars) using a combination of `tabyl` from the `janitor` package and `dplyr`.

I want to create a horizontal bar plot of the percentage data with margins of error (error bars using `geom_errorbar`), where each percentage bar is a different color (assigned by category), ordered visually from largest to smallest percentages, with the y-axis tick labels muted, and I want the color legend ordered the same as the bars.

In my original data (not the reproducible example below), I have achieved everything in the plot aside from getting the legend to order appropriately. The legend consistently orders itself alphabetically even though I attempt to manually override it. In the example here I've got the added problem of the bars ordering visually from smallest to largest rather than smallest to largest.

So there are two questions here:
(1) How do I set the legend order to agree with the desired bar order when working from a `tabyl`?
(2) How do I consistently get bars to go the direction I want in a horizontal `geom_col()`?

Example below. (Forgive the verbose `ggplot` customizations; I wanted to include everything from my real plot to help figure out if there's some sort of code in there that's screwing things up.)

CODE UPDATED (6/20/2022, 8:51 PM EST):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(janitor)

temp <- tribble(
  ~ Category,
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
)

temp_n <- temp %>%
  nrow()

temp_tabyl <- 
  temp %>% 
  tabyl(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Category = factor(Category,levels = c("CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
                                               "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA", 
                                               "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB", 
                                               "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
                                               "EEEE"))) %>% 
  rename(Percent = percent) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Percent)) %>% 
  mutate(CI = sqrt(Percent*(1-Percent)/temp_n),
         MOE = CI * 1.96,
         ub = Percent + MOE,
         lb = Percent - MOE)

temp_tabyl %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Category, 
               x = Percent,
               fill = str_wrap(Category,40)),
           colour = "black"
  ) + 
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(
      y = Category,
      xmin = lb,
      xmax = ub
    ),
    width = 0.4,
    colour = "orange",
    alpha = 0.9,
    size = 1.3
  ) + 
  labs(colour="Category") +
  geom_label(aes(y = Category, 
                 x = Percent,
                 label = scales::percent(Percent)),nudge_x = .11) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent,limits = c(0,1)) + 
  labs(title = "Plot Title",
       caption = "Plot Caption.") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = 'Roboto'),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14,
                                face = 'bold'),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    axis.text.y=element_blank()
  ) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(colour = 'white'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(.5, 'cm')) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(as.factor('Category'),
                             byrow = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(limits = c("CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
                                 "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA", 
                                 "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB", 
                                 "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
                                 "EEEE"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was this bit in the `geom_col` portion of the `ggplot` code: `fill = str_wrap(Category,40)`. Somehow that fill argument didn't play well with `scale_fill_discrete`, which is why Jared's initial solution didn't work, but his updated answer gets us most of the way there.

So the solution steps were:

1. Remove the `str_wrap` command from the `geom_col` `fill` argument.
2. Add `scale_fill_discrete(labels = ~ stringr::str_wrap(.x, width = 40))` to the end of the `ggplot` code.
3. Add `y = "Category"` to the labs element in the ggplot (to override the yucky y axis title that would otherwise result from the reordering command).

Huge thanks to @jared_mamrot for helping me troubleshoot!

Also appropriate citation from another post that offered the solution: [How to wrap legend text in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71501905/how-to-wrap-legend-text-in-ggplot)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test

temp <- tribble(
  ~ Category,
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
)

temp_n <- temp %>%
  nrow()

temp_tabyl <- 
  temp %>% 
  tabyl(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Category = factor(Category,levels = c("DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
                                               "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB", 
                                               "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA", 
                                               "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
                                               "EEEE"))) %>% 
  rename(Percent = percent) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Percent)) %>% 
  mutate(CI = sqrt(Percent*(1-Percent)/temp_n),
         MOE = CI * 1.96,
         ub = Percent + MOE,
         lb = Percent - MOE)

temp_tabyl %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(y = reorder(Category,Percent),
               x = Percent,
               fill = Category),
           colour = "black"
  ) + 
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(
      y = reorder(Category,Percent),
      xmin = lb,
      xmax = ub
    ),
    width = 0.4,
    colour = "orange",
    alpha = 0.9,
    size = 1.3
  ) + 
  labs(colour="Category",
       y = "Category") +
  geom_label(aes(y = Category, 
                 x = Percent,
                 label = scales::percent(Percent)),nudge_x = .11) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent,limits = c(0,1)) + 
  labs(title = "Plot Title",
       caption = "Plot Caption.") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(family = 'Roboto'),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14,
                                face = 'bold'),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    axis.text.y=element_blank()
  ) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(colour = 'white'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(.5, 'cm')) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(as.factor('Category'),
                             byrow = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = ~ stringr::str_wrap(.x, width = 40))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to set limits for the 'fill' scale, re https://r-graphics.org/recipe-legend-order

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test

temp <- tribble(
  ~Category,
  "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D"
)

temp_n <- temp %>%
  nrow()

temp_tabyl <- 
  temp %>% 
  tabyl(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Category = factor(Category,
                           levels = c('D','B','A','C'))) %>% 
  rename(Percent = percent) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Percent)) %>% 
  mutate(CI = sqrt(Percent*(1-Percent)/temp_n),
         MOE = CI * 1.96,
         ub = Percent + MOE,
         lb = Percent - MOE)

temp_tabyl %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Category, 
               x = Percent,
               fill = str_wrap(Category,40)),
           colour = "black"
  ) + 
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(
      y = Category,
      xmin = lb,
      xmax = ub
    ),
    width = 0.4,
    colour = "orange",
    alpha = 0.9,
    size = 1.3
  ) + 
  labs(colour="Category") +
  geom_label(aes(y = Category, 
                 x = Percent,
                 label = scales::percent(Percent)),nudge_x = .11) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent,limits = c(0,1)) + 
  labs(title = "Plot Title",
       caption = "Plot Caption.") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
#    text = element_text(family = 'Roboto'),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14,
                                face = 'bold'),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    axis.text.y=element_blank()
  ) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(colour = 'white'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(.5, 'cm')) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(as.factor('Category'),
                             byrow = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(limits = c("C", "A", "B", "D"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

Thank you for editing your minimal, reproducible example to better illustrate the problem; I believe the `fill = str_wrap(Category,40)` is causing an issue with the long variable names. If you change that to `fill = Category` then format the labels in scale_fill you should solve the problem, i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(janitor)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'janitor'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     chisq.test, fisher.test

temp <- tribble(
  ~ "Category",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
  "EEEE",
)

temp_n <- temp %>%
  nrow()

temp_tabyl <- 
  temp %>% 
  tabyl(Category) %>% 
  mutate(Category = factor(Category,levels = c("CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
                                               "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA", 
                                               "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB", 
                                               "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
                                               "EEEE"))) %>% 
  rename(Percent = percent) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Percent)) %>% 
  mutate(CI = sqrt(Percent*(1-Percent)/temp_n),
         MOE = CI * 1.96,
         ub = Percent + MOE,
         lb = Percent - MOE)

temp_tabyl %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Category, 
               x = Percent,
               fill = Category),
           colour = "black"
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(
      y = Category,
      xmin = lb,
      xmax = ub
    ),
    width = 0.4,
    colour = "orange",
    alpha = 0.9,
    size = 1.3
  ) + 
  labs(colour="Category") +
  geom_label(aes(y = Category, 
                 x = Percent,
                 label = scales::percent(Percent)),nudge_x = .11) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent,limits = c(0,1)) + 
  labs(title = "Plot Title",
       caption = "Plot Caption.") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
 #   text = element_text(family = 'Roboto'),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14,
                                face = 'bold'),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
    axis.text.y=element_blank()
  ) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(colour = 'white'),
        legend.spacing.y = unit(.5, 'cm')) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(as.factor('Category'),
                             byrow = TRUE,
                             reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(limits = c("CCCCC CCC CCC CC CCCCC CCC CCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCCC CCCCCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCC CCC C CCC",
                                 "AAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA", 
                                 "BBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBB BBBBBBB", 
                                 "DDDDD DD D DDD DDDD DDD DDDDDDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDD DDD DDD DDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD DDDDDDD",
                                 "EEEE"),
                      labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, width = 40))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jared. This was the solution I'd initially turned to, but (for whatever reason) it doesn't work on my real data. Again, I've replicated my true data and code (which I obviously can't share) to the best of my ability and just changed the contents of the data table. I have no idea why this works in the example but fails on the true data. When I add the equivalent of `scale_fill_discrete(limits = c("C", "A", "B", "D"))` to my real code, it corrects the legend order, but it makes the bars in the plot gray.

Comment: Sorry ran out of space in last comment. It also overrides the legend spacing which is important because my true categories are quite long and I want them to wrap in the legend.

Comment: FYI, that spacing is the result of `fill = str_wrap(Category,40)),` in `geom_col`.

Comment: Sorry @Abe, if I can't reproduce the problem it's very difficult to help you troubleshoot. It sounds like you have something 'weird' going on. I understand you can't share your data, but perhaps you can share your 'full' ggplot code (e.g. the actual Category names etc)?

Comment: Hey @jread_mamrot, I've updated the code to better reflect my true data, which now (with your suggested `scale_fill_discrete` addition) produces the gray bars problem I referenced above. All I did was change the factor values to include spaces between the "words" within each category (reflective of how my actual categories are structured, as multi-word levels). Can you confirm you get the grey bar problem?

Comment: Brilliant. Yes, I think the spaces will cause an issue with the wrapping. If you just change the labels it should be fine. Give me 2 mins and I'll edit my answer

Comment: I've actually found the solution! I will post it momentarily. Thanks for your pushing.

Comment: Glad you figured it out; I just updated my answer to show a potential solution